# Are all resistance bands the same?

Tags: resistance

I am planning to buy a resistance band to do weighted pushups, stretching and assisted pull ups. Are all resistance bands the same? Will they all give me the same resistance/assitance?

Like, if I buy one from a local store then will it really give me good assitance and resistance?

Also, can you please link me to good amazon resistance bands if you know any? I am 70 kg and 6 feet in height. My age is 16. I can't buy bands from "america only" websites as the shipping cost is very high tho..

Thanks! :)

Answer (score 2):

Exercise resistance bands are not all alike.  The typical difference is in the [colors that indicate the amount of resistance](http://www.livestrong.com/article/145490-what-is-the-difference-in-colored-resistance-bands/).  When purchasing resistance bands, you should consider the  muscle groups you plan to target and buy bands that are appropriate for your goals.  And, since it is beyond the scope of this site (and purely opinion) to recommend what bands to purchase, you'll need to research that on your own.

Comment: Additionally, bands become easier over time as they lose their resilience. This will be hastened by high use, and/or exposure to extreme elements (Heat, cold, etc). i.e. don't store them in the garage.